# HLS Stream URL with Token not playing. 403 Forbidden

Tags: node.js, video, http-live-streaming, kodi, hls.js

I have a code to scrape m3u8 links of a site called "***streamlive.to***". The site has free links with tokens that expire every 60 mins. A sample of the link can be found [here](https://www.streamlive.to/view/69956/CBS-(SD)). And [this is the public m3u8 link for VLC](https://nl2.streamlive.to/vlc/dt0qvk6nmdhk8u6/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9OS8xMC8yMDE5IDc6MzE6MTYgUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1XK1NDbC9Kc05xYmN1NW1vMi9QZTJ3PT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTYwJnN0cm1fbGVuPTE5JmlkPTA=) on that page. Note that the token changes every hour.

My question is, pasting the link in **VLC**, it streams without issues, but if i put the link in **Movian Media Player** or **Kodi** app (*which have basic http functionalities but can stream HLS videos*), I get a **403 forbidden**. Below is a sample code in ecmascript in Movian:

```
page.appendItem(stream_url, 'video', {
    title: stream_name,
    icon: "views/img/play.png"
});
```

What could i be missing? Headers? Any help is appreciated. An implementation of streaming the link via ***nodejs*** is also appreciated.

**N/B** - *An expired token isn't the issue. I scrape the links on demand so i always have a fresh access token.*

Comment: Set the referer

Comment: @szatmary thanks a million bucks - mind putting that into an answer? It worked for me.